# Grep word within a file then copy the file

Tags: text-processing, grep, find, cp

I have a collection of files ( *.zip, *.txt, *.tar.gz, *.doc, ...etc ). These files  reside within a path. I want to find all the files ( *.txt), then copy, only, the text files that contain specific words ( e.g LINUX/UNIX).

I ran the following:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | grep 'LINUX/UNIX'
```

This command was able to find all the text files, then "grep" filtered the resultant text files by listing only the text files that contain 'LINUX/UNIX'.

How can I copy these final files (i.e. the text files that contain 'LINUX/UNIX') to a specific path of choice?

I tried to apply `xargs`

```
find . -name "*.txt" | grep 'LINUX/UNIX' | xargs cp <to a path>
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Pretty much the same as [Grep command to find files containing text string and move them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56903)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -rl --null --include '*.txt' LINUX/UNIX . | xargs -0r cp -t /path/to/dest
```

Because this command uses NUL-separation, it is safe for all file names including those with difficult names that include blanks, tabs, or even newlines.

The above requires GNU `cp`.  For MacOS/FreeBSD, try:

```
grep -rl --null --include '*.txt' LINUX/UNIX . | xargs -0 sh -c 'cp "$@" /path/to/dest' sh
```

How it works:

1. `grep` options and arguments

   - `-r` tells grep to search recursively through the directory structure. (On FreeBSD, `-r` will follow symlinks into directories.  This is not true of  either OS/X or recent versions of GNU `grep`.)
   - `--include '*.txt'` tells grep to only return files whose names match the glob `*.txt` (including hidden ones like `.foo.txt` or `.txt`).
   - `-l` tells grep to only return the names of matching files, not the match itself.
   - `--null` tells grep to use NUL characters to separate the file names.  (`--null` is supported by `grep` under [GNU/Linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), [MacOS](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html) and [FreeBSD](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/grep/) but *not* [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/grep).)
   - `LINUX/UNIX` tells grep to look only for files whose contents include the regex `LINUX/UNIX`
   - `.` search in the current directory. You can omit it in recent versions of GNU `grep`, but then you'd need to pass a `--` option terminator to `cp` to guard against file names that start with `-`.
2. `xargs` options and arguments

   - `-0` tells xargs to expect NUL-separated input.
   - `-r` tells xargs not to run the command unless at least one file was found.  (This option is not needed on either BSD or OSX and is not compatible with OSX's `xargs`.)
   - `cp -t /path/to/dest` copies the directories to the target directory.  (`-t` requires GNU `cp`.)

Comment: For Mac OS X, and probably BSD, you'll want to use --null instead of -Z. Also, I think `cp -t` is Linux-only.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Good point.  Thanks.  I updated to use `--null` and added a version for BSD/OSX that does not use `cp -t`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for the improvements.

Comment: OpenBSD `grep` does not have `--null`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks.  Answer updated to note that OpenBSD does not support `--null`.

Comment: It should be noted here that some grep colorize the output (in other words is puts additional characters into the name of the file). To silence color character use `--color=never`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz That is a good point.  Sometimes, a `grep` alias is used to turn color on.  Such aliases should use `--color=auto` rather than `--color=always`.  With `--color=auto`, grep will only colorize if the output is going to a terminal (as opposed to, say, a pipeline as is our case here).

Answer (score 14):

More portably (POSIX features only):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep -q LINUX/UNIX {} \; -exec cp {} /path/to/dest \;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following sh/Bash one liner is another method, though will only work in the current directory, and doesn't recurse:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do if grep -l 'LINUX/UNIX' "$f"; then cp "$f" /path/to/dest/; fi; done
```

The `-l` option to grep will print a list of the files which are being copied, though you could use `-q` if you don't want to see anything on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why the original string did not work. Following command works for me.

find / -name (filename*) | grep '(filename.extention)'| xargs cp -t ./

In my case filename* is collection of files with same name with different file types (txt, zip, etc). I do grep to find out only filename.txt and copy it to my destination directory (which is currently, ./).