# gnuwin bash If .txt file contains string copy file

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin, gawk

okay so i know of grep -rhi, which extrats the line if string is found, but I want to copy the entire file so for example,

file.txt >

```
isexample #new
iesameplxpele
ieamama #new
```

now if I used grep -rhi "#new", it would extract only

```
isexample #new
ieamama #new
```

where as I want all the contents within the file including

```
iesameplxpele
```

How would I do this?

Of course the .txt file must contain #new in either one of its lines.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check the return value of `grep`:

```
if grep -q '#new' "/path/to/inputfile"; then
  cp "/path/to/inputfile" "/location/of/outputfile"
fi
```

Comment: what if i wanted to run it on C:/ for example meaning there would be multiple text files with the same string?

Comment: if grep -q '#new' "c:/"; then
  cp "c:/" "/location/of/outputfile"
fi

would work?

Comment: Have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297006/grep-word-within-a-file-then-copy-the-file